# The requested URL returned error: 502, Jenkins on slave machine

Tags: git, jenkins

Does anyone knows what problem seems to be with Jenkins or Git ? I am getting the following error when trying to build job fetched from Git using Jenkins:-

```
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'http://website.com/_git/projectName.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the Git repository does not seem to be one Git would support.

A good way to check if the issue is not with Jenkins is simply to try and clone locally the repository, on one's own workstation:

```
git clone http://website.com/_git/projectName.git
```

If that does not work, it would not work either within a Jenkins job.

Comment: Is it may be proxy issue on VM, if this URL works locally ?

Comment: @VineetAggarwal Yes, if you are using a proxy locally, that same proxy should be used in your Jenkins agent.